# USB Switch possibly causing audio feedback

Tags: usb, laptop, audio, keyboard

I recently got an Aten US224 2 Port USB switch. It's used to switch mouse and keyboard between PC and laptop.
I have also recently got some new speakers and quickly noticed I would occasionally hear a kind of oscillating feedback from them.

It seems the switch is causing this, if I remove the switch from either PC or laptop the feedback goes away, same if either is turned off entirely. I can also get the feedback to stop just by removing the keyboard from the switch and if I turn the lights off on the keyboard while plugged into the switch the feedback tone changes.

I'm thinking it's a power issue on the switch? I tried plugging it's 5v input into a USB header on my motherboard but that seemed to make things worse. I've tried moving cables away from each other, doesn't seem to make much difference. Have tried both USB ports on my laptop, both on battery and mains powered.

Cheers for any thoughts on the issue

Comment: I had a problem such as this a while back. My computer is hooked to my sound system (cassette player, radio, etc.) my problem was the jack which plugged into the computer. The ground was not really grounding correctly. I switched cables of input (reciever) to the speaker out (PC) and it worked much better.

Comment: Hey thanks, I had switched the two cables between pc and laptop but that doesn't really take one out of the mix. I'll see if I can get hold of a higher quality cable from a mate and give it a shot

Comment: Interference can also be caused by wireless interference. Common issues are from radio interference from USB 3.0 ports, so when you are able, use USB 2.0 instead of USB 3...

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1565714/1274972
this solution worked for me. thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input team.

It seems the USB switch was the direct cause, I ended up plugging mouse and keyboard into my monitor's hub and passing the hub into the USB switch. This seems to have fixed the problem I was having with audio feedback.